# How we can acces the hardware registers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mmap, pymodbus, adafruit-circuitpython

I am trying to access the hardware registers in python. I found out many built in libraries like circuit python, pymodbus etc but they read/write the data on buses.Instead I read the mmap library but this library takes file instead of the addresses. Is there any way , that we could access the hardware registers and read/write the data directly in python

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by hardware registers?  You can't access the CPU registers.  Because Python is interpreted, you are several levels of abstraction away from the CPU registers.  The scripts don't even know which CPU you're using, and even if you did, the interpreter is going to mash all the registers after you try to set one.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am trying to access the zynq board remotely, and working on the PS of the zynq board. I want to acces the registers of the zynq board and read/write the values simply in python.

Comment: How is it attached?  If it is mapped into memory, then you can absolutely use `mmap` to map the registers.  Does the device have a mapped region somewhere in the `/sys` space?

Comment: On Unix, the usual architecture for accessing some specialized hardware's registers is the following:  The kernel needs to support the hardware, then you can use specialized `ioctl` calls to query and set the registers in question.

Comment: yes /sys is available but how can i use in python